# SetState is not working and giving the error of undefined in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a below snippet.

```
private hideFormAccess = () => {
this.setState(
  {
    isFormAccess: false
  }
);
};
```

This is giving error of setstate not defined but when i modified it

```
private hideFormAccess = () => {
this.setState(
  {
    isFormAccess: false
  },
  () => {
    // console.log('Test');
  }
);
 };
```

Now its working fine, but problem is that in call back i don't want any function to call (Where right now i mention the console.log).

Is there any other way to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's `private`? :)

Comment: private is just an access modifier, its a method

Comment: As far as I know, `private` is not part of JS. What language are you using? Typescript?

Comment: Yes, I am using typescript.

Comment: Is the function defined inside a `class`?

Comment: Yes, export class SomeName extends React.PureComponent

Comment: Please include a [mcve] and a clear description of the problem and the expected behaviour in the question description.

Comment: Is there is another way to do, I was able to resolve the issue, I just wanted to know if there is more good way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Either delete your own question, or post the solution as an answer to your own question if you feel anyone could benefit from it!

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Can you add more context? Just from the code you posted it's hard to say what the problem could be.